# understanding jquery div element with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I can't see where my code is wrong. I am trying to get an element with the `id` of `custom-logo-video` to change its `innerHTML` with an if statement (if it is "" or blank etc). However it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var a = $("#custom-logo-video");

    if (!a.trim()) {
        // is empty or whitespace
        a.innerHTML("easy");
    } else {
        a.innerHTML("hard");
    }

});
```

Comment: `$("#custom-logo-video");` You need quotes.

Comment: `SyntaxError: illegal character`... I highly recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/. Basically everything is wrong: You have to pass a **string** to `$`. `$` returns a **jQuery object**. It doesn't have a `trim()` method. jQuery objects also don't have an `innerHTML` method. So, yeah, you treally should follow a tutorial first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = $('#custom-logo-video').html();

    if (!$.trim(a)) {
        // is empty or whitespace
        $('#custom-logo-video').html("easy");
    } else {
        $('#custom-logo-video').html("hard");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, that works - I guess it makes sense too since I am only changing the variable and not the element - I thought changing the variable would in turn update the element...?

Comment: Don't forget to **explain** the changes you made.

Comment: var a = $('#custom-logo-video').html(); <-- changing this variable won't change what is on the page?

Comment: @user3399767 yes, "a" is a String here, change "a" will not change the "html" on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `innerHTML` which isn't necessary since you're using jQuery. `.html()` will suffice.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var a = $("#custom-logo-video");

    if ( !a.html().trim() ) {
        // is empty or whitespace
        a.html('easy');
    }
    else {
        a.html('hard');
    }
});
```

EDIT: fixed typos and logic in code.

Comment: Did you try to run the code? *edit:* still incorrect. Strings don't have an `.html` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var a = $("#custom-logo-video");
    // To check if the node is empty or not I am 
    // calling jQuery api is(':empty')

    if (a.is(':empty')) {
        // is empty or whitespace

        // To replace the innerHTML of a node you call a .html() jQuery api
        a.html("easy");
    } else {
        a.html("hard");  
    }

});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8qj6x6h8/)

Comment: Why should the OP try that? They would probably benefit from an **explanation**.

Comment: sure let me add explanation to it

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the code

```
var a = $(#custom-logo-video);
```

selection requires quotes around it

```
var a = $('#custom-logo-video');
```

When you use jquery to select, you have a jQuery object so innerHTML won't work, you want to use either .html() or .text() to get the inner text. Here is how I fixed it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var a = $('#custom-logo-video');

    if (!a.html()) {
        // is empty or whitespace
        a.html("easy");
    }else{
        a.html("hard");
    }

});
```

You can read more here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var a = $('#custom-logo-video');

    if (!a.trim()) {
        // is empty or whitespace
       a.text("easy");
    } else {
       a.text("hard");
    }

});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = $('#custom-logo-video').html();
    (a !== null && a.trim().length > 0) ? a.html('hard') : a.html('easy');
});
```